Touchdown in college football
Do the receivers have to have 2 feet in bounds in the end zone for a touchdown catch in college football?

No. The rule in college football is always 1 foot (or one body part)

ARTICLE 3.
To catch a ball means that a player:
Secures control of a live ball in flight before the ball touches the ground, and
Touches the ground in bounds with any part of his body, and then
Maintains control of the ball long enough to enable him to perform an act common to the game, i.e., long enough to pitch or hand the ball, advance it, avoid or ward off an opponent, etc., and
Satisfies paragraphs b, c, and d below.

There is no distinction in college football between the endzone and regular field for what makes a catch.
